# fill dataframe column with list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like below:

```
miles uid  
12    235   
13    234   
14    233   
15    236
```

a list **list1** like below:

```
[(39.14973, -77.20692),
 (33.27569, -86.35877),
 (42.55214, -83.18532),
 (41.3278, -95.96396)]
```

The output dataframe I want

```
miles uid lat-long               lat       long
12    235  (39.14973, -77.20692)  39.14973 -77.20692
13    234  (33.27569, -86.35877)  33.27569 -86.35877
```

How can I achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
df['lat-long'] = my_list
df['lat'] = [e[0] for e in my_list]
df['long'] = [e[1] for e in my_list]
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If length of `DataFrame` is same like length of list first column only assign and for next 2 columns use list comprehension:

```
df['lat-long'] = list1
df['lat'] = [la for la, lo in list1]
df['lon'] = [lo for la, lo in list1]
```